# Interactive Foreground Extraction using GrabCut in python,OpenCV

Tags: python, image, opencv

I want to separate the background and foreground in a set of 70 images. But when I try with `GrabCut` Algorithm, i find that along with the background, foreground is also getting deleted. And the problem is, I can't do this manually.

This is my original image:

[image]

This is the result of `GrabCut` :

[image]

Comment: In `GrabCut` you need to specify a bounding rect on your foreground! How did you do that(You said that you have to it automatically)?

Comment: @Constantine Yes, because I have 70 different images, and its difficult for me to take each image and do it separately.

Comment: It may not work just with a rectangle. After that, you may want to provide some touch ups to get better results.  Also, result may change with iterations. Please check this for a basic understanding: http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_grabcut/py_grabcut.html#grabcut

Comment: @AbidRahmanK I have been following the same tutorials only. Thats why I got this result, and I couldn't understand the second part of the code(Manually masked mask image)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aOqOwM-Qbtg, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kAwxLTDDAwU, To regain back the lost foreground, you need to specify them as foreground regions. That is what mask does.

Answer (score 1):

As you cant draw rectangle manually, best way is you can try giving the bounding box just 10-20 pixels width inside of your original image (just as an inside boundary) and try with it. 
But if your foreground object of interest is at the borders, it will get chopped out in this case.

That can be avoided to some extent by checking the biggest blobs and black pixel count of the output image and you can restore back the original pixel values for those cases till 10-20 pixel width away from border. Mostly you have to do after-check on the result and apply some heuristics to atleast restore back the portion of original image.